# Как поставить пробелы и почему они игнорируются?

Tags: javascript

```js
let jackBMI;

jackBMI = {
    name: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'White',
    height: 1.70,
    weight: 79,
    calcBMI: function(){
        this.BMI = this.weight/ this.height ** 2
        return this.BMI
    }
};
console.log(jackBMI.calcBMI());

let mikeBMI;
mikeBMI = {
    name: 'Mike',
    lastName: 'Black',
    height: 1.93,
    weight: 91,
    calcBMI: function(){
        this.BMI = this.weight/ this.height ** 2
        return this.BMI
    }
};
console.log(mikeBMI.calcBMI());


if(mikeBMI > jackBMI){
    console.log(mikeBMI.name + ' ' + mikeBMI.lastName + ' BMI ' + mikeBMI.calcBMI() + ' is higher than ' + jackBMI.name + jackBMI.lastName + jackBMI.calcBMI()) } else {console.log(jackBMI.name + jackBMI.lastName + 'BMI' + jackBMI.calcBMI() + ' is higher than ' + mikeBMI.name + mikeBMI.lastName + mikeBMI.calcBMI()) 
}
```

Comment: Я разгадал тайну... Ваше условие if не правильное и оно выводит значение else, где у вас нет ни одного пробела...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я знаю console.log() не стандартизирован. Добиться пробелов можно обратными кавычками

```js
let jackBMI;

jackBMI = {
  name: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'White',
  height: 1.70,
  weight: 79,
  calcBMI: function () {
    this.BMI = this.weight / this.height ** 2
    return this.BMI
  }
};
console.log(jackBMI.calcBMI());

let mikeBMI;
mikeBMI = {
  name: 'Mike',
  lastName: 'Black',
  height: 1.93,
  weight: 91,
  calcBMI: function () {
    this.BMI = this.weight / this.height ** 2
    return this.BMI
  }
};
console.log(mikeBMI.calcBMI());


let printResult = '';
if (mikeBMI > jackBMI) {
  printResult = jackBMI.name + ' ' + jackBMI.lastName + ' BMI ' + jackBMI.calcBMI() + ' is higher than ' + mikeBMI.name + ' ' + mikeBMI.lastName + ' ' + mikeBMI.calcBMI();
  console.log(`${mikeBMI.name} ${mikeBMI.lastName} BMI ${mikeBMI.calcBMI()} is higher than ${jackBMI.name} ${jackBMI.lastName} ${jackBMI.calcBMI()}`)
  console.log(printResult);
} else {
  printResult = jackBMI.name + ' ' + jackBMI.lastName + ' BMI ' + jackBMI.calcBMI() + ' is higher than ' + mikeBMI.name + ' ' + mikeBMI.lastName + ' ' + mikeBMI.calcBMI();
  console.log(`${mikeBMI.name} ${mikeBMI.lastName} BMI ${mikeBMI.calcBMI()} is higher than ${jackBMI.name} ${jackBMI.lastName} ${jackBMI.calcBMI()}`)
  console.log(printResult);
}
```

UPD: Еще один вариант

> собрать сначала строку в переменну, а затем ее выводить в консоль

Comment: Думал про обратные кавычки, но с ними не получалось

Comment: @Дурачок Ну вот вам 2 варианта, как можно это обойти для консоли, выбирайте какой больше нравится. P.S. Переименуйте ник, забанить могут.